# How to save KML layer as an SVG file using QGIS

Tags: qgis, kml, svg

[image]

I'm working with QGIS 3.28 LTE. I want to save a KML layer as an SVG file for manipulation with Inkscape.

How would I do this? I can't find the option under the layer Menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exporting most "final images" in QGIS is done via [print layouts](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/training_manual/map_composer/map_composer.html). This allows you to export in many formats, including vector formats like PDF and, as you mentioned, SVG.

1. Go to `Project` > `New Print Layout` or press `Ctrl`+`P`
2. Name your layout and press `Ok`
3. Use the `add map` tool on the left toolbar to add your canvas. You switch to your main QGIS project and toggle layers on and off as appropriate, and updating the print canvas by pressing the refresh icon at the top toolbar.
4. Once happy, press `export as SVG`:

[image: 1]

5. I would recommend ticking `Export map layers as SVG groups`, unticking `Export RDF metadata` and ticking `crop to content`.
6. Press `Save`

- N.b. The SVG export function in QGIS is notoriously buggy, but for something as simple as this it should be fine.